# Embedding asm into C programming

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to learn assembly my self, and I have been reading different websites first to know the meaning of some registers, if-the, etc, and saw examples on how to use them.

However I don't find it easy to understand. This program finds certain letters and counts them in a board using a bidimensional array. I want to replace the part of the functions `void print_results()`, and `void count()` with assembly code since this is very easy in regular C code.

I am not sure how to start so I am more interested on just a good start, specially on how to pass the variable from void `read_board()` to the function `void count()` to count the letters found, after that I think I can be on my own.

I appreciate any help, Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *inputFilePtr;
char board[7][7];

void usage() {
    printf("usage: one filename argument.\n");
}

void read_board() {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i != 7; i++) {
        for (j=0; j != 7; j++) {
            fscanf(inputFilePtr, "%c", &board[i][j]);
        }
        fscanf(inputFilePtr, "\n");
    }
}

void count() {

     __asm__("\
      ");

}

void print_results() {

}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        usage();
        return 1;
    }

    inputFilePtr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inputFilePtr == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open file, %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    read_board();

    count();

    print_results();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assembly isn't a standard thing like C.  It depends very much on what processor you're using.  You'll need to look up the precise calling conventions of your processor / compiler to understand how exactly to mix C and asm.  For example, things like which registers are used for passing arguments can vary.

Comment: What compiler are you using ?

Comment: I am using linux fedora, and I use gcc

Comment: The inline asm syntax for GCC is described in http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want the C-equivalent that does your current asm part.

Since you array board is global and your board size is fixed (7x7), you don't need pass anything to count(). This will do:

```
void count() {
int i, j, count = 0;
char = 'X'; //Replace with whatever char you want to count 

  for (i=0; i != 7; i++) {
        for (j=0; j != 7; j++) {
          if(board[i][j] == c)
             count++;
       }
   }
}
```

Then simply call count() from wherever you want.

In case if you want to know how to pass parameters to functions (if the board, i & j are not global like your case):
call count as: `count(&board[0][0], int i, int j);`

Receive the parameters as: `void count(char **board, int i, int j)`

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much Mr. Thiruvalluvar that will help.

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, you ask for *calling conventions*. Maybe this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct (source) solution in asm, but here are some links you might, or might not have read:

GAS, x86?

- [X86 Assembly/GAS Syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax), this page has a very easy to read instruction by instruction. Click the [X86_Assembly](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly) link at top to get the whole *"book"*.
- [Writing Assembly-Language Functions ...](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html) GCC; Has a ***Examples*** section with some C-code <-> asm lists.
- [User guide to the gnu assembler as version 2.17](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/as/index.html#Top)
- [Using Assembly Language in Linux (http://asm.sourceforge.net)](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html), has some info on intel vs AT&T syntax. (as do wiki book above). Also look at the ***Syscalls with > 5 args.*** down a bit on the site.